# How to filter by count after groupby in Pyspark dataframe?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark dataframe like this.

```
data = [("1", "a"), ("2", "a"), ("3", "b"), ("4", "a")]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data).toDF(*("id", "name"))
df.show()
+---+----+
| id|name|
+---+----+
|  1|   a|
|  2|   a|
|  3|   b|
|  4|   a|
+---+----+
```

I group by this dataframe by name column.

```
df.groupBy("name").count().show()
+----+-----+
|name|count|
+----+-----+
|   a|    3|
|   b|    1|
+----+-----+
```

Now, after I groupby the dataframe, I am trying to filter the names that their count is lower than 3. For example, here I am looking to get something like this:

```
+----+-----+
|name|count|
+----+-----+
|   b|    1|
+----+-----+
```

Comment: `df.where(col('count')<3)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filtering and counting negative/positive values from a Spark dataframe using pyspark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52334485/filtering-and-counting-negative-positive-values-from-a-spark-dataframe-using-pys)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

data = [("1", "a"), ("2", "a"), ("3", "b"), ("4", "a")]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data).toDF(*("id", "name"))
df.groupBy("name").count().where(F.col('count') < 3).show()
```

`F` is the alias of functions, you can use any **identifier** you want, but it is usually written as `F` or `func`, which is just a personal habit.

result:

```
+----+-----+
|name|count|
+----+-----+
|   b|    1|
+----+-----+
```